# isset($_POST[deletePhoto]) does not work

Tags: php, mysql, post, isset

I have a function where I want to delete Photos form my database. But my function is not getting in the `isset($_POST[])`. I have tried it with an `echo` and I have checked the submit. I'm just a student in PHP so I hope its not a dumb question

These are my functions.

```
function showDeleteForm(){
    global $connection;
    $id = $_GET['id'];
    if (isset($_SESSION["login"]) && $_SESSION["login"] == 2) {
            echo 
                '<form id="deleteButton" action="photo.php?id='.$id.'" method="post">
                <button type="submit" name="deletePhoto">Delete</button>
                </form>';
    }
}

function handleDeleteForm(){
    global $connection;
    if(isset($_POST['deletePhoto'])){
        $id = $_GET['id'];
        $result = mysqli_query($connection, "DELETE FROM `i296297_studie`.`photos` WHERE id= '$id'");
        header('Location: categorie.php');
    }
}
```

Comment: For just an advice,From now on, save Pictures in file and just save their id in database! That's the best type of working with pictures.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 Yes, because this is not my only function. I have tested the query in phpmyadmin and when I changed '$id' in a number for instance 57 the row is getting deleted.

Comment: Where did you test the `echo` ? Do you know if you pass in `if(isset($_POST['deletePhoto']))` ?

Comment: @Alban Pommeret I have tested the `echo` in my `if(isset($_POST['deletePhoto']))` and deleted the var `id` the `result` and the `header()`.

Comment: @Arif_suhail_123 I forgot to call the function `handleDeleteForm()` I didn't know that this was necessary  now it is working! thanks to everybody who put time in my problem!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `mysqli_error($connection);` in your query.

and if that work. Means no error

Check may be you forget to call the `function`.

Comment: Thank you this is working! I forgot tot call in the `function`